# How come my csv-file isnt being read all the way?

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

So the general idea is that I read in a csv-file using the following code:

```
 try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File(path));
            sc.useDelimiter(";");
            while (sc.hasNext()){
                String lijn = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(lijn);
            }

        }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println(path);
            System.out.println("definition.csv not found");
        }
```

All goes well until I hit line 82 where it just stops reading even though there are over one thousand lines left and nothing in the file itself seems to indicate a change in punctuation.

the file

```
province;red;green;blue;x;x
1;42;3;128;Vestisland;x
2;84;6;1;Austisland;x
3;126;9;129;Tyrconnell;x
4;168;12;2;Tyrone;x
5;0;15;130;Ulster;x
6;168;45;177;Blekinge;x
7;84;21;131;Oriel;x
8;126;24;4;Breifne;x
9;168;27;132;Connacht;x
10;0;30;5;Kildare;x
11;42;33;133;Dublin;x
12;84;36;6;Ossory;x
13;126;39;134;Thomond;x
14;168;42;7;Desmond;x
15;0;45;135;Ormond;x
16;42;48;8;Leinster;x
17;84;51;136;Hereford;x
18;126;54;9;Dyfed;x
19;168;57;137;Glamorgan;x
20;0;60;10;Gwent;x
21;42;63;138;Gloucester;x
22;84;66;11;Oxford;x
23;126;69;139;Wiltshire;x #Salisbury
24;168;72;12;Surrey;x
25;0;75;140;Sussex;x
26;42;78;13;Winchester;x
27;126;84;14;Dorset;x
28;84;81;141;Somerset;x
29;168;87;142;Devon;x
30;0;90;15;Worcester;x
31;42;93;143;Cornwall;x
32;84;96;16;Middlesex;x
33;126;99;144;Faereyar;x
34;168;102;17;Shetland;x
35;0;105;145;Innse Gall;x
36;42;108;18;Orkney;x
37;84;111;146;Caithness;x
38;126;114;19;Teviotdale;x
39;168;117;147;Ross;x
40;0;120;20;Moray;x
41;42;123;148;Buchan;x
42;84;126;21;Strathearn;x
43;126;129;149;Gowrie;x
44;168;132;22;Atholl;x
45;0;135;150;Argyll;x
46;42;138;23;Fife;x
47;84;141;151;Clydesdale;x #Strathclyde
48;126;144;24;Lothian;x
49;168;147;152;Carrick;x
50;0;150;25;Galloway;x
51;42;153;153;Dunbar;x
52;84;156;26;Northumberland;x
53;126;159;154;Cumberland;x
54;168;162;27;Isle of Man;x
55;0;165;155;Westmorland;x
56;42;168;28;Durham;x
57;84;171;156;York;x
58;126;174;29;Lancaster;x
59;168;177;157;Chester;x
60;0;180;30;Perfeddwlad;x
61;42;183;158;Lincoln;x
62;84;186;31;Leicester;x
63;126;189;159;Derby;x
64;168;192;32;Gwynedd;x
65;0;195;160;Powys;x
66;42;198;33;Shrewsbury;x
67;84;201;161;Warwick;x
68;126;204;34;Northampton;x
69;168;207;162;Bedford;x
70;0;210;35;Norfolk;x
71;42;0;163;Suffolk;x
72;84;3;36;Essex;x
73;126;6;164;Kent;x
74;168;9;37;Guines;x
75;0;12;165;Boulogne;x
76;42;15;38;Yperen;x
77;84;18;166;Artois;x
78;126;21;39;Brugge;x
79;168;24;167;Zeeland;x
80;0;27;40;Holland;x
81;42;30;168;Westfriesland;x
82;84;33;41;Sticht;x
83;126;36;169;Gelre;x
```

EDIT : link to csv-file https://mega.co.nz/#!vhJHWJBR!VC2ib4FlLbCxlDaMFhM-bocAcJISJTW_lxoXRBkYJUE

Comment: This is CSV; then why don't you use a library such as OpenCSV to read it all?

Comment: What is exactly the line it stops at? What does it contain?

Comment: @ fge because I'm a noob at csv and thought my method would be easiest. I have never heard of OpenCSV

Comment: @jsalonen line 82 as stated in OP . The lines in the csv-file start with the linenumber.

Comment: So there are just problems with the file itself and not with my code?

Comment: There _is_ a problem with your code; but, really, try OpenCSV before reinventing the wheel again. Hint: you use `Scanner`, so understand the difference between `.next()` and `.nextLine()`, especially since you use a custom delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The line below appears to be problematic:

```
   while (sc.hasNext()){
        String lijn = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(lijn);
   }
```

Try changing this to:

```
   while (sc.hasNext()){
        String lijn = sc.next();
        System.out.println(lijn);
   }
```

Note that this code should now be printing every `;`-delimited field on a different line, which may or may not be what you were originally trying to do, but I assume your actual intent was to store the CSV in memory in some form, and this should help with that.

Comment: @BURNS, Just edited my answer. If the change above also doesn't work, then I think you might want to upload your file somewhere, so we can see the original file. It is difficult to guess what's happening because sometimes invisible characters are lost when you paste into SO.